# Struts2 & Spring error: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: spring, struts2, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

My project is using Spring 3.2 and Struts2 (both using annotations).  I am configuring Spring through Java.  When I try to inject a service into an action, I get the following error from Struts2:

> 1. No qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>      autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>      {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> 2. Could not autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
>      com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>      qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>      dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>      candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>      {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> 3. Error creating bean with name 'com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>      autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
>      com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>      qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>      dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>      candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>      {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> 4. Unable to instantiate Action, com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction, defined for 'login' in namespace '/Login'Error creating bean with name
>      'com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction': Injection of autowired
>      dependencies failed; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>      autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
>      com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>      org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>      qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>      dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>      candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>      {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Here is the Stacktrace:

> Unable to instantiate Action, com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction,
>   defined for 'login' in namespace '/Login'Error creating bean with name
>   'com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
>   com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> ```
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:316)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:536)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction': Injection
> ```
>
> of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
>   com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:203)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:183)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:536)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService
> ```
>
> com.ceiwc.mvc.action.LoginAction.userService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:203)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:183)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:536)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ceiwc.mvc.service.IUserService] found
> ```
>
> for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:203)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:183)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
> org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:536)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
> ```

Here is the Java configuration for Spring:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ceiwc")
public class ApplicationConfig {

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(ApplicationConfig.class)
@PropertySource({ "classpath:db.properties" })
public class DataConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { environment
                .getProperty("db.packagesToScan") });
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean()
                .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Here is my DAO:

```
public interface IUserDao extends IGenericDao<User> {
    public User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}

@Repository("userDAO")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User> implements IUserDao {

    @Override
    public User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {

        Query query = getEntityManager()
                .createNativeQuery(
                        "Select u From User Where username = :username And password = :password");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        query.setParameter("password", password);

        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Here is my Service:

```
public interface IUserService {
    public User validateUser(String username, String password);
}

@Service("userService")   
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User validateUser(String username, String password) {
        return userDao.findUserByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
    }

}
```

Here is my action:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Namespace("/Login")
@Component
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private User user;
    private String updateFlag;

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @Action(value = "login", results = { @Result(name = "success", location = "/pages/login/login.jsp") })
    public String login() {
        updateFlag = "Y";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "validate", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", location = "/pages/menu/index.jsp"),
            @Result(name = "login", location = "/pages/login/login.jsp") })
    public String validateUser() {
        if (updateFlag == null) {
            return LOGIN;
        }

        if (userService.validateUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) == null) {
            addActionError("You are an invalid user");
            return LOGIN;
        }

        // TODO: Add session aware info
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUpdateFlag() {
        return updateFlag;
    }

    public void setUpdateFlag(String updateFlag) {
        this.updateFlag = updateFlag;
    }

    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>menuAdministration</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Helps with wiring the application together -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Needed to manage the Java based @Configuration classes for Spring -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ceic.config</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Handles Strut2 URL requests -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What am I missing?  I have the `@Component`, `@Service` and `@Repository` stereotypes.  So, I'm not understanding why Spring can't find my bean for injection.

Comment: I don't see any obvious flaw in your code. You can try a clean/rebuild/redeploy in your IDE, to see if some classes are missing in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: @Guillaume, when I check my .war file, I see that the classes are there.  That's why I'm perplexed as to why Spring isn't seeing the bean.

Comment: Is the Spring container being bootstrapped?

Comment: @NuAlphaMan Could you post a web.xml and/or spring-config.xml?

Comment: @RomanC, web.xml posted.  My spring-config.xml is blank at the moment because I'm using annotations.  I left it there for those who follow behind me and may be more comfortable with XML.

Comment: @NuAlphaMan Is this a typo in package name `com.ceic`?

Comment: @RomanC, that definitely was a typo.  It should have been com.ceiwc!  Now, I'm getting a no action mapped for namespace!  This is freaking irritating!

Comment: Don't you have mapping an action via annotations, post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two solutions to this problem.

1. Since I am using Java configuration for Spring, I had to ensure that my `contextConfigLocation` was set properly.
2. I am using a jar file that contains beans with Spring stereotypes, so I had to ensure that the jar file was being properly built-in eclipse.  When building the jar file, I had to ensure that the Add Directory entries options were checked.

These two steps solved this problem.